# Why does my router show 4 different SNR margin figures?

Tags: networking, router

The DSL log page of my router (Asus DSL-AC68U) shows a SNR Margin value for 'Downstream' under a heading of 'Line Stats' plus three more values for SNR Margin under a heading of 'VDSL Band Status', one for D1, one for D2 and one for D3 (and corresponding upstream ones)

I understand what SNR is and the difference between the ratio and the margin but please can someone explain what I the router shows one figure for 'downstream' plus three other (slightly different) figures for D1, D2 and D3?

Which figure gives me the better idea of my overall line quality?

[image]

Comment: Could be the VDSL band profiles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSL#Profiles

Comment: I'm afraid  that Wiki page didn't help to explain my question very well, it just explains what profiles are. Are you saying the modem in my router is using 4 different frequencies? If so, what is the 5th SNR margin figure?

Comment: I would assume that your router is capable of using bands 8 (U0 -uplink only?), 12 (U1/D1), 17 (U2/D2), and 30 (D3 - downlink only?) and negotiates bands with the receiving equipment to get the fastest rate on both sides. If one band has a shockingly low SNR then it will switch to the next. I don't know for sure as I'm not a telecoms engineer hence only a comment but https://uktechhub.com/forums/topic/understanding-vdsl-band-status-on-dsl-log-status-page-u0-u1-u2-d1-d2-d3/ seems to suggest the same.

Comment: That's a useful link, so maybe the single 'downstream' value is some sort of average of the three bands? Although the average of D1, D2 and D3 isn't 5.6 as shown in the top half of the screenshot so my question still stands in case anyone else knows what the  top figure is. Can't seem to get the info from Asus